# Why can't Windows search find the Registry Editor?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, search

[image]

Clearly the window name is Registry Editor.

[image]

The command to run it is regedit though.

Oddly enough it can't find "regedit" until all the letters have been spelled out, which strikes me as odd.

[image]

Why can't Windows search find the app "Registry Editor"? Is it the way search was designed? I don't think this is localized just to the registry editor as there are far more programs that I have trouble with where it can't search it up by name but by the command, and even then partial commands still don't bring it up.

Comment: Isn't this because "regedit" doesn't start with or contain "Registry Editor"?

Comment: Last I checked, the program was called "Registry Editor", not "regedit". Look, I can search for "Google Chrome" even though the command is "chrome" and it will find it both ways.

Comment: This is because for Chrome there is a shortcut on your computer called "Google Chrome". If you make a shortcut to regedit, for example, and name it "Registry Editor" somewhere on your computer, then when you search for Registry Editor, it will show up. I believe for it to show up under "Programs" and not "Files" is where that shortcut is located

Comment: Addition to my comment: I noticed if I move my "Registry Editor" shortcut to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs for example then it will show up as a "program" when I search. Keep in mind I am doing this on Windows 7 but believe 10 behaves similarly

Comment: add .exe to the end of it. I have to do that with most commands via start. for instance `appwiz` won't work, but `appwiz.cpl` will. same with `compmgmt` vs `compmgmt.msc` or `eventvwr` vs `eventvwr.exe`

Answer (score 0):

You can move the shortcut to start menu programs, but it is not done as with other microsoft "admin" programs to avoid non"admins" using it. why regedit? because The name is Registry Editor, but in the location it is stored, it is regedit.exe It is same with gpedit.msc If you want you can run cmd (command prompt, cmd.exe for short) and type `title SomeTesting Thing` and see, how it changes it name. the title is easily changable and doesn't really matter in names.